# Let $f:(0;\infty)\times (0;\infty) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a Lebesgue measurable function, is $T_f(y)=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x,y) \, dy$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:(0;\infty)\times (0;\infty) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a Lebesgue measurable function. Lets define
$$T_f(y)=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x,y) \, dy$$
$$G_f(y)=\int_0^{+\infty} |f(x,y)| \, dy$$
By Tonelli's Theorem I know $G_f$ is measurable and I also know $G_f \in L^p(0;+\infty)$ (take it as an hypothesis). I would like to say $\Vert T_f \Vert _p \le \Vert G_f \Vert _p$ so $T_f \in L^p(0;+\infty)$ but I need $T_f$ to be measurable in order to be abel to calculate $\Vert T_f \Vert _p$. Is this true? How can I prove it?

Comment: $T_f$ is a pointwise limit of measurable functions (truncate the integral at $n$, then you can use the full Fubini theorem)

Comment: wich is the difference between "full Fubini Theorem" and "Fubini Theorem"?

Comment: To me Fubini-Tonelli refers to the Fubini theorem when everything is non-negative (which is easier). By “full Fubini” I thought of the theorem when your function is not non-negative. So nothing really important.

Comment: Thank you!! I think I got it

Comment: Nol, in fact the integral defining $T_f$  need not exist. (Yes if $f$ is integrable on the product space.)

Comment: @Mindlack ??? There's no reason the integral should exist, truncated or not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Indeed there is a simpler answer. $G_f$ is $L^p$ thus locally $L^1$ thanks to Holder. Thus by Fubini $T_f$ is locally measurable, thus measurable.

Comment: @Mindlack I missed the absolute value in the definition of $G_f$ and the hypothesis that $G_f\in L^p$ - sorry.